# Using Glide to load an image from remote storage

Tags: android, picasso, shared-hosting, android-glide, godaddy-api

I am developing an **android** app that needs to load many images from a folder that is located on my online server (in this case a GoDaddy hosting shared-plan).

All of the images are stored in an image folder **inside the FileManager folder provided by GoDaddy.**

**Glide** needs a URL to load an image, but in my case these images are not public and can't be reached from a HTTP URL (and should remain that way).

**I would like to use glide to load these remotely stored images just like I am able to do so locally by providing a local path to the images on my local machine**

For example this code works locally where path = (C:\Users\user\images\myImage.png) notice that it is **not** https:// url .

`Glide.with(mContext)
      .load(C:\Users\user\images\myImage.png) 
      .into(mImageView);`

The path provided here is local and works on my local machine, **I would like to replace localPath with remoteStorageFolderPath** but I am unsure how it is done. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I think this has already been brought up as an [issue in Glides Github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1579), and was solved by TWiStErRob on 10 Nov 2016. The way to do it is to add an authorisation header as follows:

```
LazyHeaders auth = new LazyHeaders.Builder() // This can be cached in a field and reused later.
    .addHeader("Authorization", new BasicAuthorization(username, password))
    .build();

Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(new GlideUrl(url, auth)) // GlideUrl is created anyway so there's no extra objects allocated.
    .into(imageView);
}

public class BasicAuthorization implements LazyHeaderFactory {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public BasicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String buildHeader() {
        return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```